# Twilio IVR Database Integration Two Inputs?

Tags: php, twilio, ivr

I have played around with database integration on Twilio, but how would I be able to ask for two inputs such as tracking number and password, and then for a status to be read if both are correct?

My main aim here is to protect our clients who need to get updates on their cases so that others cannot just randomly press a load of numbers and inadvertently get someone's update messages.

Do you have any coding example?

I've been adapting their PHP examples which are given in their How-to guides.

Thank you very much in advance for your help,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

So the pattern you can use in this scenario is basically something like this:

An inbound call causes Twilio to request the URL you have specified for your Voice Request URL.  That URL returns TwiML.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml

Maybe the `<Say>` verb telling Twilio to prompt the user for the first input (lets say tracking number) and the `<Gather>` verb to listen for the caller to enter tones.  As part of the Gather verb you need to include the *action* parameter which tells Twilio what URL to request once the Gather completes.

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="/gather-tracking-number.php">
        <Say>Please enter your tracking number</Say>
    <Gather>
</Response>
```

Once the user enters their tracking number and the Gather completes, Twilio will request the URL specified in the Gather verbs *action* parameter. As part of the request Twilio will pass you the digits the caller entered.  Your app needs to persist those somehow.  Database, session, whatever.

This URL also needs to return TwiML with the next prompt in it.

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="/gather-passcode.php">
        <Say>Please enter your customer pass code</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Also, as a cheap way of maintaining state across the request/responses, you can use the querystring.  For example to pass the tracking number to the next page in your workflow you can throw it in the URL like this:

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="/gather-passcode.php?trackingnumber=" . _REQUEST["Digits"]>
        <Say>Please enter your customer pass code</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's great, thank you for taking the time to help me. I will have a play around with that.